# Typescript: Class generic which in turn extends another generic class

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I'm doing a basic web service which should connect to a database to do basic crud operations. Since these operations are repetitive I made a generic `Service` class which takes a model & dto as types.

```js
import { UserModel, UserModelDTO } from './models';

interface Serviceable {
  doSomething()
}

class Service<M, DTO> implements Serviceable {
  public model: M
  
  constructor(model: M) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  read(): Array<DTO> {}

  doSomething() {}
}

class UserService extends Service<UserModel, UserModelDTO> {}

const userService = new UserService(UserModel)
const records = userService.list()
```

At this point everything is working fine and I can declare as many services as I want, but I hit a wall after I tried to connect these services to controllers, since again, I'm making simple CRUD operations I also wanted to define a Generic Controller in which I can use any service as long as it inherits from the original `Service` class

```js
class GenericController<T extends Service> {
  public service: T;
  
  constructor(service: T) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  read(req, res, next) {
    const records = service.read()
    return records;
  }

}
```

After declaring this the compiler tells me that I must satisfy the generics types for the Service class, but that defeats the whole purpose of what I'm trying to do.

I tried searching for an example to do this, so it's very probable I'm looking for the wrong thing or I'm mistaken on my declarations.

Comment: The code shown above "At this point everything is working" has some errors/omissions. Where does the `list` method come from in `UserService`? There isn't any defined in your code. Also, there's an error on `read` as it defines a return value but doesn't actually return anything. Perhaps `read` was meant to be abstract?

Comment: How do you intend to use `Controller`? Will there be a `UserController` subclass, etc.? Or is `Controller` meant to be used directly?

Comment: It was an error I made, `list` should be `read` and I didn’t include the definition for the read method since I don’t think it’s important on the context of the question.

Comment: I plan to use UserController as a subclass of Controller, I’m intending to make Controller a generic that can receive any Service I declare, but the compiler forces me to satisfy the generic types I declared on Service

Comment: When you leave things out like that, please include a comment describing what was missing, so things are clear to people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `T extends` type parameter constraint, you can also pass type arguments to `Service`:

```
class GenericController<M, DTO, T extends Service<M, DTO>> {
    // etc.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7CXARgGxQG8AoZc5AEwHtVqBbCMAC1AHMAKASgC5kNqwSgG4SAXxIkE+OAGdZaTNggAeALIAaZABEAKgHkAfMmD0ADoUbgF6KFhwFiZCmYCuBbMnrVKEfHzVJCmQEahBZMChXBDBqKA5vX39kNS5kUmDglmBZADpEv2QAXi8fP1FgiWdyKAg4Sm4+AEEoKDgATxU9I3TkWrBXKBBkAG0AXWQq4Jo6RmyQTjSiSfFJaTkFAHEIEGhsAGEwyOp8Qih1LW6tXWQIAA9IEEobJSQLnQNDYwyXd3xPWSvCB8XSiaohMIRKIxOIcQF2ZQgpbgrKsPLw+woEoY5QVChTCi1eocWoARy0tVkWl2D2RmQooXCYD6EFCUGexWQ2XRQNyRIaXBRhKYg2GtTZzzx5CqVRIQA)